# Druid datasource storage size is greater than Hive orc size

Tags: hive, druid

I'm new to Druid.We are using Druid-Hive integration.Loading data from hive.

Exploring the size taken between Druid datasource & Hive ORC.

**Created druid datasource:**

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE druid_table STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.druid.DruidStorageHandler' AS SELECT `tme` as `__time`, `dm1`, `dm2` FROM druid_source_test;

**Created Hive external table:**

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hive_table STORED AS ORC AS SELECT `tme` as `__time`, `dm1`, `dm2` FROM druid_source_test;

Same set of data in both tables.Hive orc table size is 25MB whereas Druid datasource occupies around 60MB of storage.

Druid indexing zip file has following files. Why druid size is larger than hive orc? Druid compression occurring in my case? Am i missing some configuration to accomplish the compression? Experts kindly clarify.

version.bin

factory.json

00000.smoosh

meta.smoosh